# How to ask a poll question

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there a way to ask a poll question that allows members to provide feedback? I know this type of question (one without an obvious answer) is frowned upon, but I've seen it on other sites and was wondering if there was an approved way to do it here. Ideally, it would also have a feature to tally all the votes, and then provide the results. For example:

What is your preferred music notation system?
A. Staff paper
B. Finale
C. Sibelius
D. MuseScore
E. Other

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there are no supporting features for polls.  As you say, they are discouraged on Stack Exchange.

http://www.strawpoll.me/ seems to be a very popular site for creating such polls, though.  You could consider making one and posting it in [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room).